# /scoreboard teams leave confuses players with teams

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have a problem with this command: `/scoreboard teams leave <team> [players...]`

Here's an example: let's say we have `Player1` that belongs to `Team1` and `Team2`, when I enter `/scoreboard teams leave Team1 Player1` the command block removes from every team registered 2 players: `Player1` and `Team1`. What am I doing wrong? It seems like it confuses players with teams. I'm using Vanilla Minecraft 1.8.8 and only Optifine is installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for `/scoreboard teams leave` is:

```
scoreboard teams leave [players...]
```

A player cannot belong to multiple teams at once. To remove Player1 from their team (which will be either Team1 or Team2, but not both), use the following command:

```
/scoreboard teams leave Player1
```

Comment: Oh, it was so obvious but so stupid.. I think I'll have to wait the tag feature of Minecraft 1.9.. Thanks!!